# What's the best practice to fix an already merged feature branch on Git Flow

Tags: git, git-flow

Imagine a feature branch, let's call it **Feature A**, that was finished and then merged into **Develop** branch. A few feature branches later, while working on branch **Feature C**, which has the features added on **A**, you find out that **Feature A** has a bug that needs to be fixed.
What is the best way to accomplish this? Go back to branch Feature A, fix the bug and merge again into develop? Fix on branch Feature C? Fix on develop? Cherry pick? Or other option?

```
 A---A---A     B---B     C---C -> found a bug on A here
/         \   /      \  /
S-----------AA--------BB--- develop
```

Answer (score 1):

> Go back to branch Feature A, fix the bug and merge again into develop?

Absolutely not. In fact that branch should have been deleted everywhere the moment it was merged.

If there's a bug in the current state, make a ticket, fix the bug on a branch, make a pull request, and merge, just like any other change. There's nothing special about this situation. The fact that the bug grows out of a past branch is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the severity and prioritization of the issue.

---

If this feature is required for the functionality of the application as a whole and is critical enough to warrant an immediate fix you should likely branch from develop, create a fix, and then merge back into develop. This will supply the fix to your entire project. This is probably the most Git Flow like method. The "fix" is a feature branch itself, just like any other feature branch.

---

If feature C depends on this functionality and you performed the previous action you can now merge develop into C and continue to develop C.

If feature C, and only feature C, requires this fix due to it exposing some edge case or something then it's safe to commit the fix as its own atomic commit on branch C. That way it will be fixed with the introduction of feature C but if it becomes necessary it can easily be ported to develop later as well. However, this will delay the fix being applied until it's ported (via cherry-pick or whatever) or until the deployment of feature C.

---

The end goals is accomplished in any case. Eventually the fix is merged into the primary branch. The only question is how quickly must this be done. That's a question for your project and requires knowledge of how this bug affects your users. It's not really an issue of Git Flow directly.